# Не получается зайти пост-запросом в instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, instagram

Недавно начал заниматься BeautifulSoup'ом и поставил себе задачу вывести все названия каналов или пользователей в instagram'е

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78'
}

payload = {
    "username":"Мой номер",
    "password":"Мой пароль"
}
session = requests.Session()

answ = session.post("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher",data = payload)
base_url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
request = session.get(base_url,headers=headers)
soup = BS(request.content, "lxml")
divs = soup.find("a",class_ = "FPmhX notranslate  nJAzx").text
print(divs)
```

но выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qw.py", line 20, in <module>
    divs = soup.find("a",class_ = "FPmhX notranslate  nJAzx").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Сохраните `request.content` в файл и посмотрите там те классы. Скорее всего, часть страницы рендерится на стороне клиента через js. Если это так, то `bs4` не поможет -- ему нужен html. Можно попробовать https://github.com/psf/requests-html там по описанию есть js-движок

Comment: Или Selenium например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ищете в HTML сущность по имени автогенерируемого класса. Каждый раз при обновлении страницы имя класса будет другим, что спровоцирует `soup.find` возвратить `None`, у которого `has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Нет, при обновлении страницы имя класса то же самое